# Windows azure - Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: c#-4.0, azure, azure-storage

We are getting the below exception while reading data using JsonTextReader

***Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.***

JsonTextReader jsonReader - parameter

```
 while (hasRecords(jsonReader, JsonToken.StartObject, null, null)) //Row
        {
            ...

            //it's ok to read this all into memory - it's just one row's worth of data
            JArray values = (JArray)JToken.ReadFrom(jsonReader);
```

Also, including the code for HttpPost implementation for better clarity

```
 HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler() { Credentials = taskProfileInfo.Credential };

        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler) { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(taskProfileInfo.CommandTimeout) };
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


        HttpResponseMessage response;

        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
        request.Content = new StringContent(postBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        //using (var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
        //{
        //    using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        //    {
        //        responseFromAPI = reader.ReadToEnd();
        //    }
        //}

        return new JsonTextReader(new StreamReader(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()));
```

Appreciate if any one can help us ..

Edit: Please note that we are able to debug it locally and works fine. Only problem when we run this as **Worker Role** in Azure Cloud service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally addressed this issue. Just to close this (might help someone) -

[After doing remote debugging](http://thingsondotnet.blogspot.in/2014/09/remote-debugging-windows-azure-cloud.html) we found the below inner exception : 
**{"The request was aborted: The request was canceled."}**

And, the root cause for this issue is that we did set the timeout to less than what the actual read (JsonTextReader) operation would take. The below line of code which sets the time out :

```
 HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler) { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(taskProfileInfo.CommandTimeout) };
```

**So, the FIX is to increase time out value** so that request will not be cancelled while reading data.

Comment: Thank you for documenting this. I was getting the same error and this helped!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed increasing the seconds in the web config, it's an alternative:

```
sessionState timeout="50"
```